# Sparse matrix / vector product, how come some code using knowledge about the matrix structure is a lot slower than naïve optimised code?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, sparse-matrix, least-squares

I have some sparse system of which I know the structure. I implemented a naïve sparse matrix / vector product, which has no informations on the structure of the matrix, and a version of that product that use the knowledge of the structure. The naïve one ends up being 50% faster !
I am new to that type of optimisations, and to assembly interpretation, so I am having a hard time understanding why.
godbolt link : https://godbolt.org/z/dEn9xEWvs

Hello !
godbolt link : https://godbolt.org/z/dEn9xEWvs
I'm starting to look at optimising some c++ code. I first tried to use some SIMD instruction, but it quickly turned out that my compiler was probably more capable than me at handling that stuff. So I tried at least making things easy for it :
I am solving some sparse linear system. I did use the Eigen library to test all my stuff, but now am trying (let's say it's an exercise) to re-implement some of it. I have some naïve sparse matrix and vector structures looking like this :

```
struct triplet
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    float val; 
};

typedef std::vector<triplet> matrix;
typedef std::vector<float> vector;
```

I also have that naïve sparse matrix/vector multiplication :

```
void naiveMatMul(const matrix & A,const vector & B, vector & result)
{
   for(auto & coef : A)
   {
    result[coef.i] += coef.val * B[coef.j];
   }
}
```

This code runs fine, and for matrices of around 100k coefs, iterating around 3000 matrix/vector product takes around 200ms on my machine.

I actually know that this sparse system is composed of a set number of row of 8 coefs, then of another number of rows of 2 coefficients. So i tried implementing this to "help" my compiler :

```
struct packedMatrix
{
    struct packedCoef{unsigned int col; float val;};
    std::vector<packedCoef> coefs;
    unsigned int row_8;
    unsigned int row_2;
};

void packedMatMul( const packedMatrix &A, const vector &B, vector & result)
{
    unsigned int currentLine=0;
    unsigned int currentCoefIdx = 0;
    while(currentLine<A.row_8)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            result[currentLine] += A.coefs[currentCoefIdx].val * B[A.coefs[currentCoefIdx].col];
            currentCoefIdx++;
        }
        currentLine++;
    }
    while(currentLine<A.row_2)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            result[currentLine] += A.coefs[currentCoefIdx].val * B[A.coefs[currentCoefIdx].col];
            currentCoefIdx++;
        }
        currentLine++;
    }
}
```

I didn't take the time to unroll the inner for, as I believe the compiler should do that easily.

Not only that code wasn't faster in any way, it also ran around 50% slower (~300ms for the same number of matrix/vector multiplication). I'm surprised, especially as that naïve implementation does not presuppose anything about the order of the coefficient, while they are actually sorted and grouped by lines in the "packed" implementation. I was under the impression that this - especially the grouping of 8 values - could somehow help the automatic vectorisation of that code -even though it's more about horizontal summing than vertical..
Also, looking at the assembly (cf the godbolt link), the naïve version seems a lot shorter, but I believe it is just that the packed one indeed did unroll the "8" and "2" loops.
Is there anything obvious I am missing ?
Thank you for your help :)

EDIT : after reading the comments of Peter Cordes and Homer512 - thanks a lot !- , I did those two additional changes (and both were required for any vectorisation to appear)

1. used -ffast-math
2. and used temporary accumulator inside each inner for loop, then assigned it to result[currentLine] after each loop.
   I did that in godbolt, and afterward we do see assembly looking like this :

```
movss   xmm0, dword ptr [r9 + 4*rdx]    # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
lea     edx, [rcx + 5]
movss   xmm1, dword ptr [r9 + 4*rsi]    # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
lea     esi, [rcx + 6]
              .
    .
    .
    #then later
unpcklps        xmm1, xmm0                      # xmm1 =   xmm1[0],xmm0[0],xmm1[1],xmm0[1]
unpcklps        xmm2, xmm3                      # xmm2 = xmm2[0],xmm3[0],xmm2[1],xmm3[1]
movlhps         xmm2, xmm1                      # xmm2 = xmm2[0],xmm1[0]
unpcklps        xmm5, xmm4                      # xmm5 = xmm5[0],xmm4[0],xmm5[1],xmm4[1]
    .
    .
```

which looks like vectorisation, so at least this is having an effect ! Unfortunately, I still don't see any improvements in the computation time in my program when making those changes. I'm using Visual studio, for which I believe the equivalent to -ffast-math should be /fp:fast ? But no luck so far.
updated godbolt : https://godbolt.org/z/PnYjKGrd9

Comment: Without `-ffast-math`, compilers aren't allowed to reorder the horizontal sums, and SIMD's not very good for that anyway.  But could help some

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand know that `result[currentLine]` cannot alias any of the inputs. Therefore you may notice in the assembly it stores constantly (`movss   dword ptr [r10], xmm0`) and reloads the inputs that should not change. Simply using a local variable and storing at the end of the loop should already help.

Comment: Thanks both of you ! I edited my post with additional changes using both of your suggestions. I do see some vectorisation appearing in godbolt afterward, which is great already !
 I unfortunately don't see any changes in my actual program (I'm using Visual studio, for which the equivalent to -ffast-math should be -fp:fast ? but no luck so far..).

Comment: It would be much easier to vectorize if you don't interleave indexes and values in `packedCoef`, but store two separate arrays (search for "Array of Structures", vs "Structure of Arrays" in combination with SIMD). For testing this, just use a `vector<float>` and a `vector<int32_t>` -- you can later reduce the storage overhead, if you know that the sizes match and never exceed 8 elements, but this should have no impact when just reading values.

Comment: One thing that's not immediately obvious to me is whether the access to `B` via `B[A.coefs[currentCoefIdx].col]` has worse locality of data than the original `B[coef.j]`.

Comment: I'll be back working on that in a few days. I've seen people mentioning that vectorisation doesn't help as much for sparse matrix X vector product, as the bottleneck is often data accessing (because we're accessing either the coefficients of the matrix A or the coefficient in B in a "random" pattern, and not sequentially) which makes a lot of sense.